# Why aren't 1 and -1 included in the graph of signum fuction?

Tags: functions

[source : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function#/media/File:Signum_function.svg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hATqe.png)

As you can see in the graph that 1 and -1 are open circles and aren't included. But the range of the signum function is {1,0,-1} so I'm unable to understand why 1 and -1 are open circles in the graph and whereas 0 isn't because the function is discontinuous at 0.

Comment: How would you draw the graph in such a way that the value at $0$ is $0$, but everywhere else it's either $-1$ or $1$?

Comment: Possibly because the Fourier series converges to 0 at 0.

Comment: @Dayton This question has nothing to do with Fourier series.

Comment: Review the definition of a function.

Answer (score 4):

The function has to take one value at zero only, so you have to choose between $-1, 0, 1$ when defining it. Here $0$ is chosen